# Serial upvoting on community-wiki answers reversed, user reputation decreases?

Tags: discussion, bug, voting

Today I upvoted some [recent community-wiki answers with 0 score](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a0%20wiki%3ayes%20is%3aanswer) to get some questions off from the unanswered queue, maybe I voted too fast, like briefly reading through the question and answer for a minute then upvoted.

Unfortunately, many of these votes are reversed. Yet I found the upvotee whom I casted most of my votes on, namely 40 votes, has [a $-70$ in reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85506/40-votes?tab=reputation&sort=post)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the script subtracted the non-existent benefit of CW upvotes. If this was the case, I would lose more than 70 points. In the thread   [Does reversal of serial voting on community wiki posts affect reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145372/)  Shog9 explained how CW reversal works:

> if you didn't gain any reputation for a vote, you shouldn't lose any for it. That doesn't mean you won't ever lose rep for invalidated votes on CW posts though, if the votes were cast prior to the CWification of it.

But also added:

> the script can go out of its way to consume votes over a longer period of time when it's sufficiently spooked.

I guess this is what happened here.

Comment: Is there a way to see which posts' votes are reversed?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Not really. In principle, I could go through the reputation tab, counting votes and comparing them to the present scores. But I have better things to do than that.

Comment: So there is no automated way to do that, noted, thanks.